# Parsing a String using String Methods

Tags: string, parsing

I'm having trouble with this program. The goal is to parse a name(as a string) using string methods. I'm only able to get the first and last name however I'm having trouble with prefixes. This is what I have so far any help is appreciated!

Comment: Add an example of what you want from a sample name string.

Comment: Can you provide an example input of "textBox1.Text"? The way you are trying to approach this is extremely hacky and really dependant on the input being in a really specific format.

Comment: @ArghyaC  ah sorry, the prefix, first, and last name are supposed to be output on three different labels. so if someone were to put Mr. Doug Socks, label 1 would = Mr., label 2 = Doug, and label 3 = Socks

Comment: My most honest suggestion would be to capture the info as three separate textboxes. In my case, I would type "Ing. Alejandro Ariel González Cimé", not fitting your "rules"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I understand is that a full name can contains Initials, FirstName, MiddleName and Last Name. There would be a few combinations which can be taken care while fetching the spiliting the name from full name.

### **First Case**

```
string fullName = "Mohit Shrivastava";
var names = fullName.Split(' ');
string firstName = names[0];
string lastName = names[1];
```

### **Second Case**

```
string fullName = "Mr. Mohit Shrivastava";
var names = fullName.Split(' ');
string prefix= names[0];
string firstName = names[1];
string lastName = names[2];
```

### **Third Case**

```
string fullName = "Mr. Mohit Kumar Shrivastava";
var names = fullName.Split(' ');
string prefix= names[0];
string firstName = names[1];
string middleName = names[2];
string lastName = names[3];
```

in your case Case Second will serve your need. If you are not sure what the user is going to put as his/her name than probably you can count the count the item in names array and see if which case fits for you.

Comment: I haven't learned the split function yet, but this works. I'm not allowed to use this but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
var parts = fullName.Replace("  ", " ").Trim().Split(' ');
lastName = parts[parts.Length - 1];
if (parts.Length >= 2)
   firstName = parts[parts.Length - 2];
if (parts.Length >= 3)
   prefix = parts[parts.Length - 3];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to make the assumption that a name will be either prefix + space + firstname + space + lastname or firstname + space + lastname, then couldn't you just use the Split function? As below (untested):

```
string[] parts = fullName.Split(' ');
if (parts.Length > 2)
{
    label1.Text = parts[0];
    label2.Text = parts[1];
    label3.Text = parts[2];
}
else
{
    label2.Text = parts[0];
    label3.Text = parts[1];
}
```

If you can't be sure about the name entries though, you might want something more robust, like three different Textboxes for each parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution would be to have three separate text boxes for prefix, first name & last name. For now, this should work.

This is not very "short-n-simple", but handles almost all cases.

```
string prefix = string.Empty;
string firstName = string.Empty;
string lastName = string.Empty; //no MiddleName, as per your question

var fullName = "Dr. Riwaz N David"; //example

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fullName))
    return; //show error
var words = fullName.Trim().Split(' ');

if (words.Length == 1) //only firstname
{
    firstName = words[0];
    return;
}
if (words.Length == 2) //firstname, lastname
{
    firstName = words[0];
    lastName = words[1];
    return;
}

lastName = words[words.Length - 1]; //David
if (Regex.Match(words[0], "^[A-Za-z]{2,3}[.]$").Success) //Mrs. Dr. etc
{
    prefix = words[0]; //Dr.
    firstName = string.Join(" ", words.Skip(1).Take(words.Length - 2)); //Riwad N
}
else //when fullName = "Riwaz N David" no prefix
{
    firstName = string.Join(" ", words.Take(words.Length - 1)); //Riwaw N 
}
```